# sum of indice/index in 2 loops - R

Tags: r, function, loops, sum

I have 2 loops k and j and I would like to calculate an indice i that is the sum of k,j in order to save images with a name from 0 to 5000.

Here the code:

```
for(k in 1:100){
  for(j in 1:50){
  i <- ?
  r_list[[i]] <- crop(raster,extent(1,2,10,50)
  slice <- r_list[[i]]
  jpeg(filename=paste0("slice_",i,".jpg"),width=100,height=100,units="px")
  plotRGB(slice)
  dev.off()
}}
```

Comment: `i <- 100*(j-1) + (k-1) +1`

Comment: Summing k and j will give you repeated values... `vec <- rep(NA, 50 * 100);
for(k in 1:100){
  for(j in 1:50){
    vec[k*j] <- k + j
  }
};hist(vec[!is.na(vec)])`

Comment: What is the length of r_list?